# Node.js vm2 exchanging information between VM and main code using functions

Tags: node.js, node-vm2

I am using the `vm2` module, and I have some code with two functions: `get_input()` for getting some data that I have, and `display()` for showing some data, but these functions will not be defined in that code. How do I make some sort of external function that can run the `get_input()` to  give data from an array and output some data to my main code with the `display()` function? Basically I want to do this:

- Code running in vm2 makes a `get_input()` call
- Data from an array gets sent to that function
- Data is evaluated with code in the vm2 instance
- vm2 code makes a `display()` call which outputs data to another array on my main code

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `sandbox` option that you pass into the `vm2` constructor represents the "global" object inside the sandbox instance. You can pass functions too:

```
const { VM } = require('vm2');

const sandbox = {
  get_input(data) {
    return 'input:' + data;
  },
  display(data) {
    console.log('Data:', data);
  }
}

const vm = new VM({ sandbox });

vm.run(`

const array = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'blah' ];

const ret = get_input(array[1]);

display(ret);

`);
```

(output: `Data: input:bar`)